# Background colour hides above element's box-shadow

Tags: html, css

```css
nav {
  position: static;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0px rgba(149, 143, 143, 0.5);
}

main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 1fr 25%;
}

.main__center {
  background: #F2F3F5
}
```

```html
<nav> 
  <a href="#">Home</a> | 
  <a href="#">Languages</a>         
</nav> 
<main>
  <div> Main </div>
  <div class="main__center"></div>
  <div></div>
</main>
```

I can add a `box-shadow` property to the `nav` and it shows ok. Below the nav, I have a 3-col `main` where the center has a different bg color. When I added that color or white to either grid cols, I lose the nav box shadow. Is there a way to make the box show show no matter if main element is scrolled up underneath the `nav`? Adding `position: relative; z-index: -1` to `main` works but nothing is clickable within `main`.

```html
<nav></nav>
<main>
  <div></div>
  <div class="main__center"></div>
  <div></div>
</main>
```

Style:

```css
nav {
 position: static;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0px rgba(149,143,143,0.5);
}

main {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 25% 1fr 25%;
}

.main__center {
 background: #F2F3F5
}
```

Comment: position:relative to nav will fix your issue. No need any other property or z-index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of assigning a negative Z-index to `main`, just assign your `<nav>` as `position: relative`:

```css
nav {
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0px rgba(149, 143, 143, 0.5);
}

main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 1fr 25%;
}

.main__center {
  background: #F2F3F5
}
```

```html
<nav> 
  <a href="#">Home</a> | 
  <a href="#">Languages</a>         
</nav> 
<main>
  <div> Main </div>
  <div class="main__center"></div>
  <div></div>
</main>
```

Comment: `nav` is static as ive said.

Comment: Yes I know, but changing to relative solves the issue. I didn't notice anywhere you have stated that you cannot change the properties of `nav`?

Comment: Ahh! But I need static and wish not to use `fixed` as id need to give `main` so padding or more styles in other places. If not possible then I'll "work with it"

Comment: Why do you need `static` over `relative`?

Comment: No it's my mistake. I wanted to use 'sticky'.